# python program that count modified binary digits by using regular expression

Tags: python, string, count, binary

I want to write a program in python, by using regular expression, that can count n numbers of digits (modified binary numbers) from a file that contain binary number
for example want to count 5 digits numbers which start from 1 and end with 0, so the number will be 10000, 10010, 10100, 10110, 11000, 11010, 11100, 11110, (this is modified binary numbers)
for example if I want to count 4 digits binary number which is start with 1 and end with 1,
what I am doing is (for example/to show you, instead of file I am using a binary string)

```
a_string = '011010010111001101101111011011010110110101110011010000110010010111000100100110110101101111011011110111011001101100011011010111011001101000011001001101100011100010010110110011111011001110001001011011'

s_0 = a_string.count('1000')
s_1 = a_string.count('1010')
s_2 = a_string.count('1100')
s_3 = a_string.count('1110')


print(1000, s_0, '\n', 1010, s_1, '\n', 1100, s_2, '\n', 1110, s_3)
```

result =

1000 = 7,  1010 = 7,  1100 = 13, 1110 = 11.
Please note, want to count each binary number separately

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: Do you want to count the total amount of 4-digit numbers starting with a 1 and ending with 0 or do you want to count each of them seperately?

Comment: want to count many digits (4 or 5 or 6 or.... any number of digits) and want to count each of them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a pattern and create a dictionary.

```
(?=(1[01]{2}0))
```

- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right of the current position

  - `(1[01]{2}0)` Capture **group 1** (which will be returned by re.*findall*), match `1`, then 2 times either `0` or `1` and match a `0` at the end
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Va7R2/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ihh1vX)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?=(1[01]{2}0))"
s = "011010010111001101101111011011010110110101110011010000110010010111000100100110110101101111011011110111011001101100011011010111011001101000011001001101100011100010010110110011111011001110001001011011"

cnt = dict()
for i in re.findall(pattern, s):
    # get the value by key, or return 0 if the key does not exist
    cnt[i] = cnt.get(i, 0) + 1

print(cnt)
```

Output

```
{'1010': 7, '1110': 11, '1100': 13, '1000': 7}
```

---

For a pattern with 5 digits that starts with 1 and ends with 0:

```
pattern = r"(?=(1[01]{3}0))"
```

The output will be:

```
{'11010': 7, '10100': 3, '10010': 7, '11100': 5, '10110': 17, '11110': 4, '10000': 2, '11000': 5}
```

See another [Python demo](https://ideone.com/goZUzh)

Answer (score 0):

With your method you are including overlapping sequences in the total count. For instance, `a_string[9:13]` and `a_string[10:14]` both contain a 4-digit sequence starting with `1` and ending with `0`.

A regex may be useful if you wanted to exclude overlaps:

```
#this will output 26, while the single count() calls would sum up 38
pat=r'1\d{2}0'
len(re.findall(pat,a_string))
```